# I am a three letters word (small riddle)

Tags: riddle

> I am a three letters word,
>   why you can't digest me?
>   
>   I am a concept of, and palindrome,
>   exists in a state of incomplete transformation.
>   
>   you find me, with a little change, in your mother, 
>   change a letter to become, a star, popular.
>   
>   I am uncooked in the ancient speaking,
>   you can find me with a little digging.

What I am?

Hint#1:

> You can find me in one of the [Vedas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedas)

Comment: You might want to wait a bit longer before giving hints next time, most people won't have seen your riddle in the 6 minutes it was posted before the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this the word is

> ama

I am a three letters word,

> Yes, and straightaway hidden in clear sight :  I **am a**

why you can't digest me?

> In [ayurveda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ama_(ayurveda))  it may be a toxic byproduct generated due to improper or incomplete digestion

I am a concept of, and palindrome, exists in a state of incomplete transformation.

> Yes a pal., and in ayurveda, is the concept of something in a state of incomplete transformation.

you find me, with a little change, in your mother, change a letter to become, a star, popular.

> A short word for *a mother* is *a ma*.  Not sure about the second part.

I am uncooked in the ancient speaking, you can find me with a little digging.

> "Ama" is a Sanskrit word literally meaning "uncooked" or "undigested".
>  Maybe find with a little digging is because ama is hidden in this puzzle in the title and lines 1&3

Hint #1: You can find me in one of the Vedas

> There are four Vedas: the Rigveda, the Yajurveda, the S**ama**veda and the Atharvaveda

Answer (score 1):

It is

> YAM

I am a three letters word,

> YAM has 3 letters

why you can't digest me?

> YAM (raw ones) is difficult to digest

I am a concept of, and palindrome,
exists in a state of incomplete transformation.

> Reverse Y A M to get MAY, which in an incomplete form of 'MAYA'

you find me, with a little change, in your mother,

> Mother is MAM and with one letter change it becomes YAM.

change a letter to become, a star, popular.

> To be explored ...

I am uncooked in the ancient speaking,

> To be explored ..

you can find me with a little digging.

> Yam can be found with little digging (underground).

Comment: Its not a palindrome string :(